# My program will not open text file. Ofstream CPP

Tags: c++

I'm currently new to C++ and I've been watching a tutorial series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bYFu9mBnr4, but I'm having a big issue. My C++ code will not open a file no matter what I do, I've looked online and tried renaming it, the full path, everything I can think of. Here's my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("hello.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path() << std::endl;
    }

    file << "hello!";

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: code looks fine. Common issue is that the file or working directory is not where you think it is. You can try to use the absolute path to the file

Comment: Your code should create a "hello.txt" file in the current working directory if you have permission to write such a file there.

Comment: What ide are you using? VSCode?

Comment: Yes I'm using VSCODE

Comment: @drescherjm the code is not creating a file, and it does have permission. I also have tried using the absolute path to the file.

Comment: Search for hello.txt vscode might be set to store it somewhere else.

Comment: I like that you check for errors. That's better than what many new C++ programmers do. You can improve your error message by adding the inclusion of `<cstring>` and `<cerrno>` and instead of just printing "`Error"`, make it `std::cerr << "Error: " << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';` and you will get a better hint about what's wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks so much, this helped me find out what the error was! I think my antivirus was blocking it. Got permission denied.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Turned out to not be my antivirus, at least not that I think so. (I'm using avast) I tried disabling some features on avast for a bit, still didn't work. I even tried running it in the admin console.

Comment: @Hex You don't have the file open in another process, do you? Windows (as I assume you're using) is rather picky when it comes to simultaneous accesses to files. You may also want to print the program's current working directory: `#include <filesystem>` and then in your code: `std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';` may give a hint

Comment: @TedLyngmo No I don't have it open in anything else I also am getting an error when using the filesystem thing you just specified. ``main.cpp:16:17: error: 'filesystem' has not been declared
         cout << filesystem::current_path() << endl;``

Comment: @Hex Did you `#include <filesystem>`? Also, please drop the habit of `using namespace std;` and use the fully qualified names. It make your code easier to interpret for both humans and compilers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did, I'll add the new code to the post.

Comment: @Hex Good. I removed the old code. Not needed. What does the `current_path()` function print?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I still am getting the error though.

Comment: @Hex That's how bug-hunting goes. Baby-steps. That doesn't change even with 40+ years of doing it. What does `current_path()` print?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it still won't print anything I'm simply getting ``std::filesystem has not been declared``

Comment: Oh, you're getting a compilation error. What compiler are your using? Is it MSVC? If so, add `/std:c++17` as a compiler option. If you're using `g++` or `clang++` add `-std=c++17` (`<filesystem>` is an addition to the standard library made in C++17)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried that (I'm using g++) I got ALOT of notes, and a lot of errors.

Comment: What does the command `g++ --version`  say?

Comment: ``g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.``

Comment: ( you need to tag me, or else I won't see that you answered) - Ok, 8.1.0 is perfectly capable of using the `<filesystem>` addition. What happens if you compile manually? `g++ -o foo *.cpp -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -pedantic-errors -lstdc++fs`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I get the exact same issue.

Comment: Ok, can you execute the command I suggested above and put the complete output somewhere where I can read it, like https://pastebin.com/ and I'll take a look?

Comment: @TedLyngmo https://pastebin.com/1dwuHphN

Comment: @Hex Is that really the output from the program you show in the question? I'm asking because [this](https://godbolt.org/z/aMha3xb3M) is what I get with the same compiler.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's a compiler error I believe, it happens when I attempt to compile it.

Comment: @Hex Indeed - but check the link in my previous comment. It has your program + the same compiler and the compiler options. No compilation errors.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's really weird, should I try reinstalling g++ or something?

Comment: @Hex I don't think a reinstallation is necessary,. It may be me over-simplifying the issue but I do have a hard time figuring out how the exact code in the question can cause the compilation errors you get. I may have to sleep on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about this question, it may have been a dumb issue. Turns out IT WAS my antivirus. Avast kept blocking it, it was just looking out for me. I decided to change my antivirus afterwards and it now works fine!